# How to perform set operations in XPath-1.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

I've seen on SO and other places that the following is supposed to work (this example is lifted directly from O'Reilly's XSLT Cookbook):

```
(: intersection :)
$set1[count(. | $set2) = count($set2)]

(: difference :)
$set1[count(. | $set2) != count($set2)]
```

and it looks like it should be OK, however this seems to fail when used with actual paths rather than variables. For example, given the following document

```
<a>
  <new>
    <val>1</val>
    <val>2</val>
  </new>
  <old>
    <val>2</val>
    <val>3</val>
  </old>
</a>
```

and the XPath expression `/a/new/val[count(. | /a/old/val)=count(/a/old/val)]/text()` I would expect to get the node-set `{ 2 }` but instead am getting `{ 1 2 }`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of your problem and for a simple and easy one-liner XPath expression - solution -- no other answer proposes a solution at this moment. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The formulas for node-set intersection use node-identity, not value identity.

Two nodes are identical if and only if `count($n1|$n2) =1`

However, you want to intersect based on value identity.

**Solution**:

**Use**:

```
/a/new/val[. = /a/old/val]
```

this selects any `/a/new/val` for which there exists at least one `/a/old/val` element such that the string values of these two elements is the same.

Comment: Nice answer! Can we do implement set *Minus* operations also ?

Comment: Ok... Set *Minus* is `/a/new/val[not(. = /a/old/val)]`. Am I right?

Comment: @Babai, Yes, but see the statement that in XPath set means something different.

Comment: I didn't catch you.. could you repeat please ?

Comment: @Babai, "The formulas for node-set intersection use node-identity, not value identity"

Comment: Okay.. Got now. But then what about *Minus* operations?

Comment: @Babai, If you don't mix node identity with value identity and always remember that these define two different concepts of "sets", then this is OK.

Comment: unexpectedly powerful operator! it can implement the function of "in" in SQL, but it seemed that no formal specification about it can be found!

Comment: @frankli22586, Yes, this was discovered by Michael Kay. In XPath 2.0 there is the `intersect` operator, which removes the need for tricks and gives way for efficient implementations.

Answer (score 2):

**Remark** that intersection always results in a single node-set composed by the nodes **in common** between the two original nodes-sets.

Also **note** that two nodes with same name and content are to be treated as two **distinct** nodes. Thus `/a/new/val/text()` and `/a/old/val/text()` have same value but they are completely distinct text nodes.

Thus your current intersection:

```
/a/new/val[count(. | /a/old/val)=count(/a/old/val)]
```

should evaluate to an empty node-set, because you are intersecting two nodes-sets without any node in common (`count()` operation will never match). You are doing something like this:

`/a/new/val` ∩ `/a/old/val` = ∅

While `/a/new` ∩ `/a/old/preceding::new` will produce `new`.