# Xpath python find node after specific text

Tags: python, html, parsing, xpath

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="someid">
    <h2>Specific text 1</h2>
    <a class="hyperlinks" href="link"> link1 inside specific text 1</a>
    <a class="hyperlinks" href="link"> link2 inside specific text 1</a>
    <a class="hyperlinks" href="link"> link3 inside specific text 1</a>

    <h2>Specific text 2</h2>
    <a class="hyperlinks" href="link"> link1 inside specific text 2</a>
    <a class="hyperlinks" href="link"> link2 inside specific text 2</a>
    <a class="hyperlinks" href="link"> link3 inside specific text 2</a>
    <a class="hyperlinks" href="link"> link4 inside specific text 2</a>

    <h2>Specific text 3</h2>
    <a class="hyperlinks" href="link"> link1 inside specific text 3</a>
    <a class="hyperlinks" href="link"> link2 inside specific text 3</a>         

</div>
```

I have to distinctly find links under each "Specific text". The problem is that if I write the following code in python:

```
links = root.xpath("//div[@id='someid']//a")
for link in links:
    print link.attrib['href']
```

It prints ALL the links irrespective of "Specific Text x", Whereas I want something like:

```
print "link under Specific text:"+specific+" link:"+link.attrib['href']
```

Please suggest

Comment: So, what is the exact output you want based on the provided XML document? This isn't clear. Please, edit your question and add this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need one XPath expression for each **h2** specific text.

Given an **h2** specific text, you can get its following adjacent **a** siblings by:

```
    //div[@id='someid']/h2[.='Specific text 1']
     /following-sibling::a[
      count( . | following-sibling::h2[1]/preceding-sibling::*)
      = count(following-sibling::h2[1]/preceding-sibling::*)
      and preceding-sibling::h2[1][.='Specific text 1']]
    |
    //div[@id='someid']/h2[.='Specific text 1' and not(following-sibling::h2[1])]
    /following-sibling::a"
```

The second `//h2` selection handles the case where **h2** is the last one.

The expression above just exploits the XPath 1.0 intersection formula:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2)=count($ns2)]
```

You can find a lot of resources about this method, lot of answers here at SO (check my answers also). I think it's not difficult to understand **how** to apply this formula, what is difficult is to understand **when** it must be applied.

Credits for the formul goes to @Michael Key. Just [google it a bit](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200008/post30140.html).

My expression has been extended with additional predicates to handle your specific case and unified (`|`) with additional expression to handle last **h2**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The output is:
 `link1 inside specific text 1
 link2 inside specific text 1
 link3 inside specific text 1
 link1 inside specific text 2
 link2 inside specific text 2
 link3 inside specific text 2
 link4 inside specific text 2` . Hence its also including links from specific text 2. Whereas I want **only** specific text 1 anchors text.

Comment: Also, if possible, provide some learning links for xpath mentioning this kind of advanced methods.

Comment: the output of: `links = root.xpath("//div[@id='someid']/h2[.='Specific text 1']/following-sibling::a[count( .| following-sibling::h2[1]/preceding-sibling::*) = count(following-sibling::h2[1]/preceding-sibling::*)] | //div[@id='someid']/h2[.='Specific text 1' and not(following-sibling::h2[1])]   /following-sibling::a")
for link in links:
 print link.xpath("string()")`

Comment: I tweaked your code to get it working! Thanks a ton! However, I would be grateful if you can slightly explain the **working** of this code... Like why is `.|` used in count() etc

Comment: I've made a test (sorry :P) and there was a flow. Now corrected in my answer. Also provided additional reference information.

Comment: Please accept/upvote the answer if you think it fulfills your question or was useful.

Comment: You also find a recent entry [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178471/how-to-perform-set-operations-in-xpath-1-0). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `starts-with(s, t)` function of XPath 2.0 to build a matching condition of a `h2`-value.

```
//div/h2[starts-with(text(), 'Specific text')]//a
```

I don't know any XPath 2.0 implementation for Python. So this will probably not work. But perhaps you can change the condition for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please be a little more specific to the code here?

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working. The reason being that 'a' is not a child of h2, rather a sibling of h2. This method would have worked if all the anchors were inside h2 though.

Comment: Sorry, got confused by your indenting :)

Comment: **a** nodes are following sibling of **h2** elements and not descendant. Your XPath will not select any **a** node currently. Also `starts-with()` is not the right approach.