# XPath: Select following siblings until certain class

Tags: xpath

I have the following html snippet:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="foo">a</td>
            <td class="bar">1</td>
            <td class="bar">2</td>
        <td class="foo">b</td>
            <td class="bar">3</td>
            <td class="bar">4</td>
            <td class="bar">5</td>
        <td class="foo">c</td>
            <td class="bar">6</td>
            <td class="bar">7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm looking for a XPath 1.0 expression that starts at a `.foo` element and selects all following `.bar` elements before the next `.foo` element.
For example: I start at `a` and want to select only `1` and `2`.
Or I start at `b` and want to select `3`, `4` and `5`.

Background: I have to find an XPath expression for this method (using Java and Selenium):

```java
public List<WebElement> bar(WebElement foo) {
    return foo.findElements(By.xpath("./following-sibling::td[@class='bar']..."));
}
```

Is there a way to solve the problem?
The expression should work for all `.foo` elements without using any external variables.

Thanks for your help!

**Update: There is apparently no solution for these special circumstances. But if you have fewer limitations, the provided expressions work perfectly.**

Comment: What you want is what is matched by the second expression you gave? It means: give me the first `.bar` child and all its following `.bar` siblings until the first `.foo`. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath : select all following siblings until another sibling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161766/xpath-select-all-following-siblings-until-another-sibling)

Comment: @nwellnhof I believe it's not a duplicate because all solutions there rely on either empty text of the node, a certain id, XSLT context and functions, or XPath 2.0. None of this applies here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question!

The following expression will give you `1..2`, `3..5` or `6..7`, depending on input `X + 1`, where `X` is the set you want (2 gives 1-2, 3 gives 3-.5 etc). In the example, I select the third set, hence it has `[4]`:

```
/table/tr[1]
  /td[not(@class = 'foo')]
  [
     generate-id(../td[@class='foo'][4]) 
     = generate-id(
         preceding-sibling::td[@class='foo'][1]
        /following-sibling::td[@class='foo'][1])
  ]
```

The beauty of this expression (imnsho) is that you can index by the given set (as opposed to index by relative position) and that is has only one place where you need to update the expression. If you want the sixth set, just type `[7]`.

This expression works for any situation where you have siblings where you need the siblings between any two nodes of the same requirement (`@class = 'foo'`). I'll update with an explanation.

Replace the `[4]` in the expression with whatever set you need, plus 1. In oXygen, the above expression shows me the following selection:

[image]

### Explanation

```
/table/tr[1]
```

Selects the first `tr`.

```
/td[not(@class = 'foo')]
```

Selects any `td` not `foo`

```
generate-id(../td[@class='foo'][4])
```

Gets the identity of the xth `foo`, in this case, this selects empty, and returns empty. In all other cases, it will return the identity *of the next `foo` that we are interested in*.

```
generate-id(
    preceding-sibling::td[@class='foo'][1]
    /following-sibling::td[@class='foo'][1])
```

Gets the identity of the *first* previous `foo` (counting backward from any non-foo element) and from there, the *first* following `foo`. In the case of node `7`, this returns the identity of nothingness, resulting in `true` for our example case of `[4]`. In the case of node `3`, this will result in `c`, which is not equal to nothingness, resulting in `false`.

If the example would have value `[2]`, this last bit would return node `b` for nodes `1` and `2`, which is equal to the identity of `../td[@class='foo'][2]`, returning `true`. For nodes `4` and `7` etc, this will return `false`.

## Update, alternative #1

We can replace the `generate-id` function with a count-preceding-sibling function. Since the count of the siblings before the two `foo` nodes is different for each, this works as an alternative for `generate-id`.

By now it starts to grow just as wieldy as GSerg's answer, though:

```
/table/tr[1]
  /td[not(@class = 'foo')]
  [
     count(../td[@class='foo'][4]/preceding-sibling::*) 
     = count(
         preceding-sibling::td[@class='foo'][1]
        /following-sibling::td[@class='foo'][1]/preceding-sibling::*)
  ]
```

The same "indexing" method applies. Where I write `[4]` above, replace it with the *n<sup>th</sup> + 1* of the intersection position you are interested in.

Comment: I believe this will only work in an XSLT context. It will not work as a stand-alone XPath expression (e.g. for [`XmlDocument.SelectNodes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Comment: @GSerg, Selenium uses the [browser's XPath capabilities](http://acdcjunior.github.io/xpath-2-3-version-selenium-webdriver-support.html). Browsers support the generate-id function as far as I can remember. Though I admit, I haven't tried it with selenium.

Comment: Unfortunately the expression doesn't work with Selenium ("invalid selector"). Apparently Firefox doesn't know the `generate-id()` function.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, looks like they have decided to make that function only available when you invoke the internal XSLT processor, [MDN shows 'XSLT specific'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/generate-id) for that function, which is unfortunate. They have it, but decided to limit its scope...

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir ...And since the `=`-operator does not compare nodes. Though you could compare content using `string()` instead of `generate-id()`, or another unique part (in your example, content is different, so it would work, but still).

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea. But how would I generalize the expression to work without knowing the set index (see my code snippet)? The `current()` function doesn't work either in Firefox.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, yes, [on that same list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions) it is listed as XSLT specific as well. Strangely, other XSLT specific functions, like `element-available`, _are_ available in XPath in Firefox... If you are _that limited in available functions_, I would go with the (slightly harder) solution provided by GSerg. Unless you could work out a common difference (as in your example, which is the string-value).

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, about generalizing the expression, this one already is. You mean GSerg's expression? Or did you mean, how to generalize the part that has to find some kind of node identity? There's another trick, that works for your special case (siblings), I'll update in a bit.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how the `.foo` element was selected (or which index is has). I just get the `WebElement` and have to write a relative XPath expression that starts with `./` (see my code snippet).

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, ah, I didn't get that, and not from your OP, which starts with `//td`. You also specified _"The expression should work for all `.foo`"_. Sorry that I misunderstood. Will update in a bit.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir That means you need to be able to [get the context of the outer predicate from the inner predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6595034/11683). Competent people say you [cannot do that with an XPath 1.0 expression](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6599393/11683). And by the way, if that is your situation, why can you not make several xpath queries against that context node? First one to get the next `foo`, if any, another two to get the two sets of `bar`, then subtract the two sets manually using referential equality?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, as GSerg says. Unless you manage to use Selenium with a browser that supports `current()` and `generate-id()`, this will be (virtuall?) impossible. The [solution by Lingamurthy solves the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32556004/111575) with a similar technique as I demonstrated, but then for the context node set to one of the `foo` td's. This requires both these functions.

Answer (score 2):

<s>So you want an [intersection of two sets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7178471/11683):</s>

- `following-sibling::td[@class='bar']` that follow your starting `td[@class='foo']` node
- `preceding-sibling::td[@class='bar']` that precede the next `td[@class='foo']` node

Given the formula from the linked question, it is not difficult to get:

<s>`//td[1]/following-sibling::td[@class='bar'][count(. | (//td[1]/following-sibling::td[@class='foo'])[1]/preceding-sibling::td[@class='bar']) = count((//td[1]/following-sibling::td[@class='foo'])[1]/preceding-sibling::td[@class='bar'])]`</s>

<s>However this will return an empty set for the last `foo` node because there is no next `foo` node to take precedings from.</s>

So you want a [difference of two sets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7178471/11683):

- `following-sibling::td[@class='bar']` that follow your starting `td[@class='foo']` node
- `following-sibling::td[@class='bar']` that follow the next `td[@class='foo']` node

Given the formula from the linked question, it is not difficult to get:

```
//td[1]/following-sibling::td[@class='bar'][
    count(. | (//td[1]/following-sibling::td[@class='foo'])[1]/following-sibling::td[@class='bar'])
    !=
    count((//td[1]/following-sibling::td[@class='foo'])[1]/following-sibling::td[@class='bar'])
]
```

The only amendable bit is the starting point, `//td[1]` (three times).

Now this will properly return `bar` nodes even for the last `foo` node.

---

The above was written under impression that you need to have a single XPath query and nothing more. Now that it's clear [you don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554690/xpath-select-following-siblings-until-certain-class/32555807#comment52984472_32555730), you can easily solve your problem with more than one XPath query and some manual list filtering on referential equality, as I already [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554690/xpath-select-following-siblings-until-certain-class/32555807#comment52988735_32555807).

In C# that would be:

```cs
XmlNode context = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//td[8]");
XmlNode nextFoo = context.SelectSingleNode("(./following-sibling::td[@class='foo'])[1]");

IEnumerable<XmlNode> result = context.SelectNodes("./following-sibling::td[@class='bar']").Cast<XmlNode>();

if (nextFoo != null)
{
    // Intersect filters using referential equality by default
    result = result.Intersect(nextFoo.SelectNodes("./preceding-sibling::td[@class='bar']").Cast<XmlNode>());
}
```

I'm sure it's trivial to convert to Java.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I stumbled on the "only ...", and read "three times" as having three situations in the example, i.e., three sets.

Comment: Yep, works for me too :). It'd be worthwhile to break it down in pieces, though, it is hard to make out the expression...

Comment: @Abel I'm not sure where to put the line breaks, it looks confusing either way. The point of the expression is nicely shown in [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7178471/11683): `$set1[count(. | $set2) != count($set2)]`, then you substitute `$set1` with `//td[1]/following-sibling::td[@class='bar']` (once) and `$set2` with `(//td[1]/following-sibling::td[@class='foo'])[1]/following-sibling::td[@class='bar']` (twice).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the technique (though I really prefer XPath 2.0 and 3.0, where this is simply expressed with the `<<` operator), but I won't be the only reader here. Anyway, it's up to you ;)

Comment: @Abel yes I like XPath 2.0 too, but the OP is specifically looking for an XPath 1.0 solution.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! But how would I generalize the second and third occurrence of `//td[1]`? I can't replace them with `.` like the first one. Unfortunately my code has too work without knowing the specific path to the `.foo` element.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir But you have to know how to select the starting `foo` element in one form or another - and the xpath for selecting it you can place instead of the three occurrences of `//td[1]`. If it is okay for you to have one `//td[1]` (that you would replace in your xpath each time you execute the query), then it must be equally okay to have it three times?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how the `.foo` element was selected. I just get the `WebElement` and have to write a relative XPath expression that starts with `./` (see my code snippet).

Answer (score 2):

If the current node is one of the `td[@class'foo']` elements you can use the below xpath to get the following `td[@class='bar']` elements, which are preceding to next `td of foo`:

```
following-sibling::td[@class='bar'][generate-id(preceding-sibling::td[@class='foo'][1]) = generate-id(current())]
```

Here, you select only those `td[@class='bar']` whose first preceding `td[@class='foo']` is same as the current node  you are iterating on(confirmed using `generate-id()`).

Comment: Hey, you use the same generate-id approach I used. Independently? ;)

Comment: @Abel Yes, I did :)  I think I made it more generic to be used by any `td[@class='foo']`.

Comment: All solutions here work with any starting point. The difference is the focus-approach (which allows you to use `current()` and makes the expression a lot simpler). But I think in Selenium, focus is typically the whole document.

Comment: @Abel No doubt, sir :) Just that I felt the OP wants to start with one of the `td` elements as he said _I'm looking for a XPath 1.0 expression that starts at a .foo_.

Comment: Unfortunately the expression doesn't work with Selenium ("invalid selector"). Apparently Firefox doesn't know the `generate-id()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward (example for 'a' td) but not very optimal:

```
//td[
    @class='bar' and 
    preceding-sibling::td[@class='foo'][1][text() = 'a'] and 
    (
       not(following-sibling::td[@class='foo']) or 
       following-sibling::td[@class='foo'][1][preceding-sibling::td[@class='foo'][1][text() = 'a']]
    )
]
```