# XMLPATH: Search for an OPTIONAL information in a flat structure

Tags: xml, xpath, intersection, flat, optional-values

I got the following XML

```
<doc>
    <start/>
    <mandatory id='x1'/>
    <optional id='foo'/>
    <end/>
    <start/>
    <mandatory id='x2'/>
    <end/>
    <start/>
    <mandatory id='x3'/>
    <optional id='boo'/>
    <end/>
</doc>
```

whose structure is flat. A coherent set of information begins with  tag but ends with  tag. Certain information within a set a mandatory, here  but others are not, here

My process uses XPATH 1.0 to first extract the starting node, and after that for each starting node, I want to have the mandatory info as well as the optional one.

**My problem is to find the proper XPATH expression to derive the optional node that fits to the current node of the iteration provided by**

/doc/start

I already gave the Kayessian XPath 1.0 Formula

[How to perform set operations in XPath 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178471/how-to-perform-set-operations-in-xpath-1-0)
[XPath select all elements between two specific elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859703/xpath-select-all-elements-between-two-specific-elements/10859928#10859928)

to derive a intersection of two sets a try

following-sibling::optional[count(. | following-sibling::end[1]/preceding-sibling::optional)=(count(following-sibling::end[1]/preceding-sibling::optional))]

Thanks a lot

cheers
Christian

Comment: Can you provide desired output? Why not use XSLT? XSLT can contain multiple XPaths and return multiple nodes.

Comment: Thanks for getting back on me. The framework is set, the application is up'n running - so I unfortunately rely on XPATH. Desired output to optain the id for the optional tag is in iteration 1 *foo*, in iteration 2 *empty (node set)* and in iteration 3 *boo*. Hope that helps. Thanks in advance