# Select specific html tags from a liste of html tag via an xpath selector

Tags: html, xpath

I want get some specific information from this html code :

```
<div class="main">    
    <div class="a"><div><a>linkname1</a></div></div> <!-- I DON'T want get the text of this 'a' tag --> 
    <div class="b">xxx</div>
    <div class="c">xxx</div>
    <div class="a"><div><a>linkname2</a></div></div> <!-- I want get the text of this 'a' tag --> 
    <div class="a"><div><a>linkname3</a></div></div> <!-- I want get the text of this 'a' tag --> 
    <div class="a"><div><a>linkname4</a></div></div> <!-- I want get the text of this 'a' tag -->  
    <div class="a"><div><a>linkname5</a></div></div> <!-- I want get the text of this 'a' tag --> 
    <div class="d"></div>
    <div class="c">xxx</div>
    <div class="a"><div><a>linkname6</a></div></div> <!-- I DON'T want get the text of this 'a' tag --> 
    <div class="a"><div><a>linkname7</a></div></div> <!-- I DON'T want get the text of this 'a' tag --> 
    <div class="a"><div><a>linkname8</a></div></div> <!-- I DON'T want get the text of this 'a' tag --> 
    <div class="d"></div>
    <div class="c">xxx</div>
    <div class="a"><div><a>linkname9</a></div></div> <!-- I DON'T want get the text of this 'a' tag --> 
    <div class="a"><div><a>linkname10</a></div></div> <!-- I DON'T want get the text of this 'a' tag --> 
</div>
```

I want get in an array the list of the link's text in the 'second' 'a' (class) tags block (between the first div with the class 'c' and the second div with the class 'c') . How can I do that via an xpath selector ? is it possible ? I don't find how do..

With my example, the expected result is :

```
linkname2
linkname3
linkname4
linkname5
```

Thank you :)

Comment: What did you try? Show your current XPath

Comment: I tried several things..my last try is : //div[@class="main"]/following::div[count(preceding::div[@class="c"]) = 1]/div/a/text() , but I get nothing :/

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a *Set* question like explained in this SO answer: [How to perform set operations in XPath 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7178471/1305969).

So applied to your specific situation you should use an *intersection* like this:

```
(: intersection :)
$set1[count(. | $set2) = count($set2)]
```

*set1* should be the follow set after `div[@class='c']` and
*set2* should be the preceding set before `div[@class='d']`.

Now, putting both together according to the above formula with

```
set1 = "div[@class='c'][1]/following-sibling::*" and
set2 = "div[@class='d'][1]/preceding-sibling::*"
```

the XPath expression could look like this:

```
div[@class='c'][1]/following-sibling::*[count(. | current()/div[@class='d'][1]/preceding-sibling::*) = count(current()/div[@class='d'][1]/preceding-sibling::*)]
```

**Output:**

```
linkname2
linkname3
linkname4
linkname5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this expression:

```
/div/div[position() > 3 and position() < 8]/div/a/text()
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say the number of div with the class 'a' may vary, I can't use an 'hardcoded' value like 3 or 8

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible solution :)

```
//following::div[@class='a' and count(preceding::div[@class="c"]) = 1]/div/a/text()
```